# How do I copy allow and block lists from one EOP policy to another?

Tags: exchange, powershell, microsoft-office-365

We have set up one Spam Filter policy in Exchange Online Protection with our allow and block sender and domain lists and we have created a second policy that we want to have the same allow and block lists.

Is there a way to basically copy or import/export the allow and block lists from one policy to the other using powershell?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It took a while to figure this out, but yes. Each list can be copied directly in a single command.

The trick was that you have to "walk" the objects returned using `ForEach-Object`. These four commands will copy all four allow/block lists:

```
Get-HostedContentFilterPolicy -Identity <source policy> | ForEach-Object {Set-HostedContentFilterPolicy -Identity <destination policy> -AllowedSenders $_.AllowedSenders}
Get-HostedContentFilterPolicy -Identity <source policy> | ForEach-Object {Set-HostedContentFilterPolicy -Identity <destination policy> -AllowedSenderDomains $_.AllowedSenderDomains}
Get-HostedContentFilterPolicy -Identity <source policy> | ForEach-Object {Set-HostedContentFilterPolicy -Identity <destination policy> -BlockedSenders $_.BlockedSenders}
Get-HostedContentFilterPolicy -Identity <source policy> | ForEach-Object {Set-HostedContentFilterPolicy -Identity <destination policy> -BlockedSenderDomains $_.BlockedSenderDomains}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just in case anyone has the requirement to clone EOP allow/block lists and stumbled upon this post as I did.

Not sure if there is a change to the cmdlets, however, using array dot references to get the commands to work.

ie:**$_.AllowedSenders.Sender**

```
Get-HostedContentFilterPolicy -Identity <source policy> | ForEach-Object {Set-HostedContentFilterPolicy -Identity <destination policy> -AllowedSenders $_.AllowedSenders.Sender}
Get-HostedContentFilterPolicy -Identity <source policy> | ForEach-Object {Set-HostedContentFilterPolicy -Identity <destination policy> -AllowedSenderDomains $_.AllowedSenderDomains.Domain}
```